# sometimes Identity isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table]
(
 [ShoppingCartID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CartTimeoutInMinutes] [int] NOT NULL,
 [MaximumOrderLimitPerUser] [int] NOT NULL,
 [MaximumOrderLimitPerSession] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
 [ShoppingCartID] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Sometimes Identity isn't working, it's start with 0 and sometimes its start with 1.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your test case look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you putting the data in there? If you are using regular `INSERT` it should start at 1. You can, however, bulk-insert into the table, or otherwise use identity-insert; in which case all bets are off:

```
create table test (
  id int not null identity(1,1), 
  name varchar(20) not null)
set identity_insert test on
insert test (id, name) values (0, 'abc')
insert test (id, name) values (27, 'def')
set identity_insert test off
select * from test
```

with output:

```
id          name
----------- --------------------
0           abc
27          def
```

Or is the problem relating to `@@IDENTITY` (in which case: use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Possible

Are you using [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)? This is invoked by some data compare tools (eg Red Gate) and has the following behaviour:

> DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED, new_reseed_value )
>
> Current identity value is set to the `new_reseed_value`.
>
> If no rows have been inserted into the table since the table was created, or if all rows have been removed by using the TRUNCATE TABLE statement, the first row inserted after you run DBCC CHECKIDENT uses `new_reseed_value` as the identity. Otherwise, the next row inserted uses `new_reseed_value` + the current increment value.

Or: are you using [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)?

These assume you are looking at the table, rather then using @@IDENTITY (as Mark suggested)